# LiFePo4 Battery management system

Tags: batteries, solar-charge-controller, lithium

I am creating a 2Ah 3 cell LiFePo4 battery using individual lifepo4 batteries, for a project that requires solar charging from a genasun mppt controller. Considering the battery is split into 3 cells, do I require a Battery management system to keep the cells balanced, and would should the mppt controller be connected directly to the BMS?

I would be using this bms https://www.amazon.co.uk/LiFePO4-Safety-Battery-Protection-Batteries/dp/B08JCZVFGN

Comment: The specifications of the BMS you linked to do not match those of LiFePO4 batteries. The maximum voltage of a LiFePO4 cell would be around 3.65V but it seems this BMS will allow up to 4.2V per cell, which would quickly destroy them. Normally a "12V" LiFePO4 pack would consist of 4S (4 * nominally 3.2V = 12.8V), and not 3S (which will nominally only be 9.6V). LiFePO4 is not the same as LiIon/LiPo.

Comment: Yes you need a LFP BMS, and you can only connect the MPPT controller directly if it's designed for charging 3 LFP cells. So, read the datasheets carefully.

Comment: Appreciate the comments, I have a 3s Genasun mppt designed for lifepo4 batteries but it doesn't have the ability to balance individual cells.